# How to clean a table of old values?

Tags: sql, performance, cron

Basically I have a table that grows very fast as it registers all user impressions. However most of the data is useless, I only need the latest entry made for each user. (The table is used to authenticate users).

I'm looking to delete the old data, so the table should end up having a stable number of rows around the total number of registered users.

I can use a cron job, then there's the option of simply adding a line at the end of the authentication script that deletes old rows. It would run on every page load.

```
DELETE WHERE `Date` < NOW() - SOME INTERVAL
```

Is this efficient, should I use a CRON JOB or what else?

Comment: if possible, use a cronjob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing this from the page would add up to the time for the user login.

That is a bad approach. Better use cronjob or some other job scheduling tool like Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you could `CREATE` a temp table to hold your latest records.

And then `DROP` old table alltogether. Faster :) dropping than deleting.

Rename your temp table to the old one.

So this logic could be in your `CRONJOB` if you prefer.